# Django - Cannot create migrations for ImageField with dynamic upload_to value

Tags: python, django, django-migrations

I just upgraded my app to 1.7 (actually still trying).

This is what i had in models.py:

```
def path_and_rename(path):
    def wrapper(instance, filename):
        ext = filename.split('.')[-1]
        # set filename as random string
        filename = '{}.{}'.format(uuid4().hex, ext)
        # return the whole path to the file
        return os.path.join(path, filename)
    return wrapper

class UserProfile(AbstractUser):
    #...
    avatar = models.ImageField(upload_to=path_and_rename("avatars/"),
                               null=True, blank=True,
                               default="avatars/none/default.png",
                               height_field="image_height",
                               width_field="image_width")
```

When i try to `makemigrations`, it throws:

```
ValueError: Could not find function wrapper in webapp.models.
Please note that due to Python 2 limitations, you cannot serialize unbound method functions (e.g. a method declared
and used in the same class body). Please move the function into the main module body to use migrations.
```

Answer (score 92, accepted):

I am not sure if it is OK to answer my own question, but i just figured out (i think).

According to [this bug report](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/22999), i edited my code:

```
from django.utils.deconstruct import deconstructible

@deconstructible
class PathAndRename(object):

    def __init__(self, sub_path):
        self.path = sub_path

    def __call__(self, instance, filename):
        ext = filename.split('.')[-1]
        # set filename as random string
        filename = '{}.{}'.format(uuid4().hex, ext)
        # return the whole path to the file
        return os.path.join(self.path, filename)

path_and_rename = PathAndRename("/avatars")
```

And then, in field definition:

```
avatar = models.ImageField(upload_to=path_and_rename,
                               null=True, blank=True,
                               default="avatars/none/default.png",
                               height_field="image_height",
                               width_field="image_width")
```

This worked for me.

Comment: Is it possible to use this, and add a custom file-path for each Field?

Comment: @Garreth00 Yes, pass file-path as parameter to `PathAndRename` class. like: `custom_path = PathAndRename("/profiles/bg-images")`

Comment: This is a great answer! Works flawlessly. Thanks!

Comment: @ip. any error? because i used exactly same code 2 days ago for another project. and worked well

Comment: Always the same error `field=models.ImageField(blank=True, max_length=255, null=True, upload_to=core.models.Organization.image_path),
AttributeError: type object 'Organization' has no attribute 'image_path'`

Comment: ^ No matter if I use a normal method or a deconstructible

Comment: oh. can't say much only with this info. i would like to see your `organization` model's `image_path`

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem but I have many ImageFile in my models

```
head = ImageField(upload_to=upload_to("head")
icon = ImageField(upload_to=upload_to("icon")
...etc
```

I don't want create upload_to wraper func for every ImageField column I have.

So I just create a func named wrapper, and it woks

```
def wrapper():
    return
```

---

I think it works just fine because I opened migration file and I found this:

```
('head', models.ImageField(upload_to=wrapper)),
```

I guess it's not effect migration process

Answer (score 1):

You can create function with kwargs like this:

```
def upload_image_location(instance, filename, thumbnail=False):
    name, ext = os.path.splitext(filename)
    path = f'news/{instance.slug}{f"_thumbnail" if thumbnail else ""}{ext}'
    n = 1
    while os.path.exists(path):
        path = f'news/{instance.slug}-{n}{ext}'
        n += 1
    return path
```

and use this method with [functools.partial](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/functools.html#functools.partial) in your model:

```
image = models.ImageField(
    upload_to=upload_image_location,
    width_field='image_width',
    height_field='image_height'
)
thumbnail_image = models.ImageField(upload_to=partial(upload_image_location, thumbnail=True), blank=True)
```

You will get migration like this:

```
class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    dependencies = [
        ('news', '0001_initial'),
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.AddField(
            model_name='news',
            name='thumbnail_image',
            field=models.ImageField(blank=True, upload_to=functools.partial(news.models.upload_image_location, *(), **{'thumbnail': True})),
        ),
        migrations.AlterField(
            model_name='news',
            name='image',
            field=models.ImageField(height_field='image_height', upload_to=news.models.upload_image_location, width_field='image_width'),
        ),
    ]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
field=models.ImageField(blank=True, upload_to="/smth", *(), **{'thumbnail': True})),
```

instead of

```
field=models.ImageField(blank=True, upload_to=functools.partial(news.models.upload_image_location, *(), **{'thumbnail': True}))
```

Comment: This is an interesting answer but it'd be better if you explained a little bit about what this code does and why you'd choose it instead of one of the established answers?