# Django 1.8 Fails migration with dynamic upload_to over a FileField

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-migrations

I've been getting the following error when trying to use migrations over a model that has a FileField with a dynamic upload_to path.

```
    field=models.FileField(null=True, upload_to=core.models.UserProfile.upload_path, blank=True),
AttributeError: type object 'UserProfile' has no attribute 'upload_path'
```

My code:

```
def upload_path(instance, filename):
    return os.path.join(str(instance.user.id),filename)

class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, related_name='userprofile')
    document_upload = models.FileField(upload_to=upload_path,null=True, blank=True)
```

Comment: Delete the migration file and run `makemigrations` again.

Comment: Since the `upload_path()` function is not inside a class, it shouldn't have the first argument `self` but rather look like `def upload_path(instance, filename)`. Did you previously try to have it inside the class? The error message also suggests to search for it there rather than in `core.models.upload_path`.

Comment: @Leistungsabfall that didn't work.

Comment: @sthzg yes its a mistake from a previous try but that's not the problem

Comment: Thought so. Did the exception stay exactly the same after you've pulled `update_path` outside to the module? Because from what it prints it searches for the `upload_path` callable inside `UserProfile`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the @deconstructor class decorator, this allows the decorated class to be serialized by the migrations subsystem

Example

```
from django.utils.deconstruct import deconstructible

@deconstructible
class UploadPath(object):

    def __call__(self, instance, filename):
        return os.path.join(str(instance.user.id),filename)

upload_path= UploadPath()

class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, related_name='userprofile')
    document_upload = models.FileField(upload_to=upload_path, null=True, blank=True)
```

Read more:

- A related topic: [Django - Cannot create migrations for ImageField with dynamic upload_to value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25767787/django-cannot-create-migrations-for-imagefield-with-dynamic-upload-to-value/25768034#25768034)
- Documentation about @deconstruct: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/migrations/#adding-a-deconstruct-method

Comment: It's an old question but I stumbled  upon it and thought it might be useful for others to have it answered :)