# Python 2.7 unbound method with Django 1.7 migrations

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, django-models, django-south

I am upgrading to Django 1.7.4 and use the new built-in migrations, but I get the following error when attempting to run `makemigrations`:

```
ValueError: Could not find function upload_callback in app_utils.
Please note that due to Python 2 limitations, you cannot serialize unbound 
method functions (e.g. a method declared and used in the same class body). 
Please move the function into the main module body to use migrations.For more information, 
see https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/migrations/#serializing-values
```

My model definition:

```
class Discount(models.Model):
    banner = models.ImageField(
        help_text=_("Banner image for this discount"),
        upload_to=upload_to('discounts/', 'title'),
        blank=True,
        null=True
    )
```

And my upload callback in `app_utils.py`:

```
def upload_to(path, attribute=None):
    def upload_callback(instance, filename):
        compact = filename[:50]
        try:
            attr= unicode( slugify( getattr(instance, attribute) ) )
            mypath = '%s/%s/%s' % (path, attr, compact)
        except:
            mypath = '%s%s' % (path, compact)
        return mypath
    return upload_callback
```

Based on the error message, it indicates `upload_callback` is unbound. So
I tried pulling `upload_callback` outside of the the wrapper function, but cannot find a way to pass in the extra `path` and `attribute` parameters passed into `upload_to`. Django's documentation is unclear how to do this, and it only specifies that `instance` and `filename` are required.

Ideally, what I would like is:

```
def upload_to(instance, filename, path, attribute=None):
    ...
```

Any ideas how I can go about achieving this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After some serious deep digging on the web, I came across this Django bug report. The solution seems to create a callable factory class:

https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/22999

More discussion here: [Django - Cannot create migrations for ImageField with dynamic upload_to value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25767787/django-cannot-create-migrations-for-imagefield-with-dynamic-upload-to-value)