# Serialize unbound method functions

Tags: python, django, django-models

I use this function in my Django models. When i use -makemigrations, i get error:

> ValueError: Could not find function wrapper in party.models.
>   Please note that due to Python 2 limitations, you cannot serialize unbound method functions (e.g. a method declared and used in the same class body). Please move the function into the main module body to use migrations.

```
 def path_and_rename(path):
        def wrapper(instance, filename):
            ext = filename.split('.')[-1]
            # get filename
            if instance.pk:
                filename = '{}.{}'.format(instance.pk, ext)
            else:
                # set filename as random string
                filename = '{}.{}'.format(uuid4().hex, ext)
            # return the whole path to the file
            return os.path.join(path, filename)
        return wrapper
```

How to do it?

Comment: Please format your code

Comment: Maybe this will help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25767787/django-cannot-create-migrations-for-imagefield-with-dynamic-upload-to-value