# Django changes filename while saving ImageField

Tags: python, django

I have a django model with a field:

```
ImageField
```

When i am saving data in it, its saving successfully. But it changes its name. 
Code i am using to save 
from django.core.files.base import ContentFile

```
def save_file(request):
    mymodel = MyModel.objects.get(id=1)
    file_content = ContentFile(request.FILES['video'].read())
    mymodel.video.save(request.FILES['video'].name, file_content)
```

Now whatever name is in

```
request.FILES['video'].name
```

(a random 36 character uid) django just changes its last some character while saving.

Here is field definition.

```
file_image = models.ImageField(upload_to='some dir path', null=True)
```

I am using django 1.9 and python 2.7

Example input and output :

if i try to pass this id as an first argument to save it stores in db with a bit different name like this

what i gave :

```
123e4567-e89b-12d3-a456-426655440000
```

output saved in db

```
123e4567-e89b-12d3-a456-426655434353
```

75% of character remains same but end of id is getting changed

Comment: Can you add your ImageField definition for more information? I guess this is an parsing issue if you add any upload_to parameter on the field.

Comment: @DenizKaplan update question with field definition.

Comment: Can you write an example output before and after the `mymodel.video.save()`? This is very strange, you can use a function for upload_to (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15140942/django-imagefield-change-file-name-on-upload) if we cannot solve this issue.

Comment: Sorry, I cannot reproduce your case, I've created a model form and I've used form.save method and the file succesfully saved in os and DB with the correct name. I hope someone helps you for this situation.